# nuget restore is not creating xml files in AWS CodeBuild windows default image

Tags: msbuild, nuget, aws-codebuild, .net-4.7.2

In AWS CodeBuild windows image **aws/codebuild/windows-base:2019-1.0** when I used nuget restore in powershell for ASP.NET MVC project(target framework version 4.7.2) that only create .dll and .pdb but not create .xml file.

And I have also try nuget.exe diff version but getting same problem every time.

I already try NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE='none' but did't worked.

expected files

[image]

but getting only .dll and .pdb

[image]

thank you in advance any help is appreciated.